# Drawing directed random walk on integer lattice

Tags: graphics, tikz-trees

Could you please help me to draw random walks in random environment. How can I draw directed random walk on lattices such as

[image]

or with different colors .  I think method is almost same. but I don't know how to start. I learned how to draw a binary tree.

[image: directed random walks on lattices]

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: What do the +and - signify?

Comment: @Aditya  plus sign means  it attracts plus sign and repels minus signs. and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfmathsetseed{3}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    % Coordinate axes
    \begin{scope}[
      semithick,
      ->,
      >={Stealth[]},
    ]
      \draw (0, -3.5) -- (0, 3.5);
      \draw (0, 0) -- (6.5, 0);
    \end{scope}

    % Ticks
    \draw[node font=\small]
      \foreach \y in {-3, ..., 3} {
        (0, \y) +(.25em, 0) -- ++(-.25em, 0)
        node[left] {$\y$}
      }
    ;

    % Random walk
    \draw[thick]
      (0, 0)
      \foreach \x in {1, ..., 6} {
        -- ++(1, {2*greater(rnd, .5) - 1})
      }
    ;

    % Random points
    \foreach \x in {1, ..., 6} {
      \foreach \y in {-3, ..., 3} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\sy{random(0, 1)}%
        \node[
          circle,
          fill=white,
          draw,
          inner sep=0pt,
        ]
          at (\x, \y)
          {$\ifcase\sy -\else +\fi$}
        ;
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Example for the second plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfmathsetseed{3}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=7.5mm,
    y=7.5mm,
  ]

    % Grid
    \draw[thin]
      \foreach \x in {0, ..., 10} {
        (\x, -6) -- (\x, 6)
      }
      \foreach \y in {-5, ..., 5} {
        (0, \y) -- (11, \y)
      }
    ;  

    % Coordinate axes
    \begin{scope}[
      semithick,
      ->,
      >={Stealth[]},
    ]
      \draw (0, -6.5) -- (0, 6.5);
      \draw (0, 0) -- (11.5, 0);
    \end{scope}

    % Random walk
    \draw[thick]
      (0, 0)
      \foreach \x in {1, ..., 10} {
        -- ++(1, {2*greater(rnd, .5) - 1})
      }
    ;  

    % Random points
    \tikzstyle{dot1} = [fill=white, draw];
    \tikzstyle{dot2} = [fill=lightgray, draw];
    \tikzstyle{dot3} = [fill=gray];
    \tikzstyle{dot4} = [fill=darkgray, draw];
    \tikzstyle{dot5} = [fill=black];
    \foreach \x in {1, ..., 10} {
      \foreach \y in {-5, ..., 5} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\sy{random(1, 5)}%
        \path[dot\sy] (\x, \y) circle[radius=2mm];
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: First of all, I am grateful. Thank you so much dear @Heiko Oberdiek. I am trying to run these codes in my latex but it gives me error message saying arrow.meta library could not be found. Then I tried to upload by using tex live utility now it says  CTAN repository is running the 2014 version and I am running the 2013. So , I am going to try to upgrade. then I will try everything. Thank you so much. I will let you know if I can manage to do so.

Comment: @Airbag Then you have TikZ < 3.0.0. Then replace `arrows.meta` with `arrows` and remove the line with `Stealth`.

Comment: I already installed 2014 version and didn't uninstall old version. So your code worked well. I am happy. but I also did as you said and still it works fine. So both case is ok. thank you so much again.